# Netcat uses different port than requested

Tags: linux, portforwarding, netcat

I have the following problem. I'm using Debian GNU/Linux Stretch and I am trying to use netcat as a simple server. I start it using following command:

```
$ netcat -l 127.0.0.1 33333
```

It starts just fine and accepts connections but on a different port than requested:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep netcat
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38782           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2851/netcat
```

This behavior is independent of requested port, user or ufw status. Recently I installed  LXC with following packages:

- apparmor
- bridge-utils
- cgmanager
- libapparmor-perl
- lxc

All have been removed later, but somehow I feel like this behavior may be related to some changes in configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using traditional `netcat` which requires providing `-p` argument for the listening port:

```
netcat -l 127.0.0.1 -p 33333
```

From `nc -h`:

> ```
>    -p port                 local port number
> ```

Syntax you use would work with [OpenBSD netcat](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/).

Comment: You saved me, bro